# Network Emulator (Netem) on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, ubuntu-16.04

Hello I'm new to Linux,

I have a Linux VM with Ubuntu 16.04 loaded onto it.  I'm trying to use a Network Emulator called Netem to delay packets.

*However when I run the ping command after I put in the delay rule, there appears to be no delay.  (see screenshot)*

[Screenshot of terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GOkRW.png)

**Below is my attempt at debugging the issue:**

1. I know that usually there is `eth0,eth1`, etc.  However when I run,
   `ifconfig` there is no `eth0` listed, just `ens33`.
2. So I substituted `ens33` and ran the command below to add the delay.
   `sudo tc qdisc add dev ens33 root netem delay 350ms`
3. Next I ping the VM to verify the delay has been added.  But the result is the same as before the delay rule was added. 
   `ping 192.168.126.130.`

Can someone please give me input as to what my issue is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're running in a VM, your network device may not be `eth0`. If you're attempting to ping localhost, then it will be using the `lo` device since it's not trying to reach a remote network address. Try applying the rule to `lo` or ping a remote address.

Comment: Thanks!!  I ended up running 'ping (some website)' and it worked perfectly.  Your a life saver!!!